# ADBannerView fails to receive ad with error 'The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable'

Tags: ios6, app-store-connect, iad, adbannerview

I started to implement iAd into a new App yesterday. But getting the error from the question title since then. **Anyone know how I can fix it?**

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114172/iad-error-ad-inventory-unavailable-apple-sample-code-also-not-working) that it might be Apples fault. But since that thread is pretty old and I couldn't find any discussion on the Apple Dev forums about it for the current time, I don't believe this is a general issue on Apples side in this case. Also the problem can't be that they don't currently have enough ads to show because that only matters in live ads.

---

**Some further information:**

I **did** enable iAd Networking in iTunes Connect for the app.

The app even appears in my iAd monetizing summary in iTunes Connect. Its 'Ad status' is set to 'Test ads' (with a yellow sign) but the **'Requests' count is 0.**

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can change your fill rate in Settings.app. Set it to 100% if you want it to show up all the time.

[image] [image]

Comment: Greate help !thask a lot

Comment: i have tried changing these settings to 100%, on device and on simulator, and re-installing/re-running the app, to no avail.

Comment: @john.k.doe Perhaps in this case it can be a different problem. It's better you open a new topic and explain what the problem is and what you have done so far.