# Unity AdBannerView

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, iad, adbannerview

The Unity ADBannerView example code is:

```
private ADBannerView banner = null;
void Start()
{
    banner = new ADBannerView(ADBannerView.Type.Banner, ADBannerView.Layout.Top);
    ADBannerView.onBannerWasClicked += OnBannerClicked;
    ADBannerView.onBannerWasLoaded  += OnBannerLoaded;
}
void OnBannerClicked()
{
    Debug.Log("Clicked!\n");
}
void OnBannerLoaded()
{
    Debug.Log("Loaded!\n");
    banner.visible = true;
}
```

My question is does the ad banner automatically go away after a set length or do I have to manually do something to get it only to display for a short amount of time, because that seems a little risky trying to interfere with an ad.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704253/adbannerview-fails-to-receive-ad-with-error-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed/22990407#22990407

This has worked well to me

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple wrapper around the ADBannerView class in iAd.framework, so it will behave just like that.

iAd's ADBannerView will stay visible as long as you set it to be (and as long as there is ad inventory).

Answer (score 0):

I think AD Banner display can be hidden.

Simply use:

```
banner.Hide();
```

wherever you want.

Or you can use `IEnumerator` to delay the time of showing this.