# iAds are not showing in my iphone app

Tags: ios, iad

Previous iads were displaying now I am getting this error:

> iAd error: Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unknown error" UserInfo=0xbbc3c10 {ADInternalErrorCode=0, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown error}

Comment: Please post the code you are using to get these Ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to settings in your iPhone to a section called Developer. Than under the iAd Developer App Testing section go to fill rate and check if the rate is 0% which will give you an error.

Comment: iAd Developer App Testing section > fill rate was 0%, now i change to 100% - always provide ad. still not able to see the iAds.

Comment: As Adam Richardson says, I cannot tell any thing till I see the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is another question related to your problem:

[iAd error "Ad inventory unavailable" (Apple Sample code also not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114172/iad-error-ad-inventory-unavailable-apple-sample-code-also-not-working)

Looks like there are sometimes problems with the iAd servers.